# Effects of changing sql table column datatype from smallmoney to money

Tags: sql, type-conversion, currency

I have to change a column datatype from smallmoney to money, because values being added to it exceed the smallmoney limit, and I can't truncate those values. Is it possible for any problems to occur from this? I know the table is accessed in multiple locations, but they are too many to go through all of them and make sure the conversion wont break anything.

Comment: Please add a tag for the database you're using.

Comment: @Barmar
I'm not quite sure. It might be MySQL or T-SQL.

Comment: What language are you programming in, and what functions do you use to perform queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing Datatype **SmallMoney** to **Money** wont affect Data already stored and Queries referring it, provided you have not used any function in the queries. It will surely affect code base if the ORM has been used, Datatype need to be changed everywhere in the codebase: Certainly, Refactoring can be used for that matter, but from a regression perspective the operations perform on it in code need to be revisited.